# Заполнение данными из Map динамически созданные View

Tags: java, android, android-studio, map, android-linearlayout

Есть метод **CreateView**, который динамически создаёт View и заполняет поля, который нахоядтся во вьюшке данными из файла SharedPrefernces.

Первый *for* **(File loadFile : loadFiles)** работает корректно. Он заполняет данными вьюшки, которые 100% находятся в файле SharedPrefernces.

Второй *for* **(Map.Entry entry : usersPresets.getAll().entrySet())** заполняет вьюшку данными, которых могут там и не находится в заданном файле. Есть - заполняет, нет - идёт дальше. И вот тут проблемка.

```
public void CreateView(File[] loadFiles) {
        if (presetsStorage.exists()) {
            for (File loadFile : loadFiles) {
                //noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
                if (!loadFile.getName().contains("userpreset_")) {
                    //noinspection UnnecessaryContinue
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if (loadFile.isFile()) {
                        String presetsName = loadFile.getName();
                        presetsName = presetsName.substring(0, presetsName.length() - 4);
                        usersPresets = getSharedPreferences(presetsName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        presetsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.presetsContainer);

                        View userPresetsView = getLayoutInflater()
                                .inflate(R.layout.preset_fragment, presetsContainer, false);
                        userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragMenubtn)
                                .setOnClickListener(viewClickListener);

                        ((CircularSeekBar) userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragA)).
                                setProgress(usersPresets.getInt("a", 0));
                        ((CircularSeekBar) userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragB)).
                                setProgress(usersPresets.getInt("b", 0));
                        ((CircularSeekBar) userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragC)).
                                setProgress(usersPresets.getInt("c", 0));

                        TextView presetFragName = (TextView) userPresetsView
                                .findViewById(R.id.userPresetName);
                        presetFragName.setText(presetsName);
                        presetFragName.setOnClickListener(viewClickListener2);

                        presetsContainer.addView(userPresetsView);
                        presetFragName.setText(presetsName.substring(11));

                        //Проблема в этом форе
                        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : usersPresets.getAll().entrySet()) {
                            if (arr.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                                // noinspection UnnecessaryContinue
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                CardView flavor_cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.flavor_cardView);
                                final View usersFlavorsPreset = getLayoutInflater()
                                        .inflate(R.layout.preset_userflavor_fragment, flavor_cardView, false);
                                ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetName))
                                        .setText(entry.getKey());
                                ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetValue)).
                                        setText(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                                flavor_cardView.addView(usersFlavorsPreset);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Мне необходимо, что бы создавалось столько новаы строк (View), сколько содержится необходимых для этого данных в файле SharedPrefernces. Сейчас оно работает, но создаёт вьюшки только на на одной строке и с каждой итерацией фора перезаписывает значения.

Скрины проблемы, которые могут помочь понять суть (но это не точно) - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx-Mv3rgZ3FyQWxWVzN2U294UVU

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда надо поставить *for* что бы значения не перезаписывались в одном и том же месте.
Надеюсь, объяснил хоть немного доходчиво. Если всё равно не понятно, попытаюсь ещё раз.

**UPDATE**: Добавил в CardView LinearLayout, и все элементы из двух файлов теперь отображаются в одном месте. Так что теперь другой вопрос - что надо изменить, что бы размещение было корректным?

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : usersPresets.getAll().entrySet()) {
                            if (arr.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                                // noinspection UnnecessaryContinue
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                LinearLayout flavor_linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.flavor_linear);
                                final View usersFlavorsPreset = getLayoutInflater().
                                        inflate(R.layout.preset_userflavor_fragment, flavor_linear, false);
                                ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.
                                        findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetName)).setText(entry.getKey());
                                ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.
                                        findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetValue)).setText(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                                flavor_linear.addView(usersFlavorsPreset);
                            }
                        }
```

[image]

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать с данными, чтобы каждое значение из массива `usersPresets` ставилось в отдельный `CardView` ?

Comment: Размещение чего? Как вам надо?

Comment: @Iman вот скрин - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ht8R.jpg. Зелёные блоки это созданная View в первом форе. Т.е. в хранилище SharedPreferences находятся два файла: "test" и "stack". Этот же первый for заполняет данными поля, которые скрыты под красной рамкой, но это не важно, там всё работает как надо. Под первым зелёным блоком "test" есть 4 строчки: "from test" и т.д. Так вот. "from test" был взят и файла test.xml. Такая же ситуация и со строчками "from stack".

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы данные из каждого файла располагались в своём блоке. В "test": "from test" и "from test 2", а в "stack" были "from stack" и "from stack 3". Сейчас же эти данные с двух разных файлов шареда лепятся в кард первого блока. Надеюсь, вы поняли)

Comment: @Haze у вас этих stack test и т.д. будет неизвестное количество или известное? Т.е. количество блоков известно сколько будет или нет?

Comment: @Iman может быть любое. Пользователь сам их шинкует сколько хочет, но в пределах разумного. Он в любом случае вводит в другой активити 4 значения: название (к примеру, test) и 3 инта для установки значения CircularSeekBar. Они записываются в SharedPreferences. И в другой активити (откуда этот кусок кода) эти 4 значения первый for раскладывает куда надо. Но вместе с этим юзер может ввести ещё, допустим, 10 других данных, которые вот и нужно разместить там, где я описал.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить условие в цикле:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : usersPresets.getAll().entrySet()) {
    if (arr.contains(entry.getKey())) {
        // noinspection UnnecessaryContinue
        continue;
    } else {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(presetsName) {
            CardView flavor_cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.flavor_cardView);
            final View usersFlavorsPreset = getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.preset_userflavor_fragment, flavor_cardView, false);
            ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetName))
                .setText(entry.getKey());
            ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetValue))
                .setText(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
            flavor_cardView.addView(usersFlavorsPreset);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло. В usersPresets.getAll().entrySet() не содержится название. Оно берётся из самого названия .xml файла. Но я понял о чём вы. Изменил на такой вариант: if (presetsName.substring(11).equals(presetFragName.getText().toString())), но всё равно результат тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы оказалось элементарным.

Изменил эту строку:

```
LinearLayout flavor_linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.flavor_linear);
```

На эту:

```
LinearLayout flavor_linear = (LinearLayout) userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.flavor_linear);
```

Теперь всё располагается там, где и должно.